# "repaint" em javascript, existe?

Tags: javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um site e nele adicionei o plugin lionscroll (para mostrar aquela barra semelhante à do Facebook, que some e aparece, dependendo da posição do cursor). Enfim, o problema é o seguinte...

Quando estou em resolução para desktop, ele funciona (assim como se estiver em versão mobile). Mas, se eu eu alterar para outra resolução, o plugin quebra o layout e faz o conteúdo sumir... se eu recarregar a página ele volta a funcionar

Exemplo, testei no navegador...

Com tamanho 1200px ele funciona, se eu mudar para 480px ele dá pau...
Se eu entrar em 480px e mudar para 1200px ele dá pau...

Gostaria de saber se tem como dar um "repaint", quando houver o evento de resize na janela, para ver se isto resolveria o problema.

Existe isso em js?

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo com HTML? jsFiddle por exemplo. As diferenças de layout são feitas com javascript?

Comment: Dá uma olha aqui http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript e aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840580/force-dom-redraw-refresh-on-chrome-mac

Comment: Um repaint não deve adiantar, você precisa ver se o seu plugin tem algum método para atualizar as dimensões após redimensionar a janela, ou reiniciar o plugin como  sugere o Paulo Maciel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o problema ocorre apenas quando você altera o tamanho da janela, você poderia desativar e ativar o plugin novamente após realizar o resize:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    // desativa e ativa plugin
});
```

Comment: Não adiantou, acontece a mesma coisa.

Comment: @Renang Coloca o seu código no http://jsfiddle.net e edita sua pergunta, assim poderemos analisar melhor o seu problema

Comment: Eu coloquei o site no ar, postei anteriormente: http://www.rxnxn2014.xpg.com.br/ Vá na aba "missões", minimize e veja. Depois carregue-a minimizada e maximize a janela.

Comment: @Renang seu problema é que o layout está definindo uma largura fixa, por isso quando você altera o tamanho da janela, o layout não se adapta. Acessei o site aqui e através do inspetor de elemento do Safari eu coloquei `width:auto;` no `<section id='mission'>` and na `<div class='kb-wrap'>` e funcionou.

Comment: Perfeito! Resolvido!